# Convert into JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to convet string into JSON object but with special characters I am not able to convert it:

String looks like when it **doesn’t have any special charaters**:

```
Var JsonString = "{"IdKey":"100008000","IdNumber":"50111112","IdType":"Single","IdTitle":"Singel Id","Name":"Nick"}"
```

And I am doing it like

```
JsonString = '{"PersonDetails":[' + JsonString + ']}';
var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(JsonString);
```

Here in JsonObject I am getting an object of array containing object(s) of class detail (Mentioned below). 
And I am adding a string PersonDetails because there is a possibility I might get multiple record so I am converting it into an Array. And inside of that array there will be multiple **objects of details class**.

But sometimes I am getting a string like:

```
Var JsonString = "{"IdKey":"100008000","IdNumber":"50111112","IdType":"Single","IdTitle":"Single id “VIP”","Name":"Nick"}"
```

Here **IdTitle is: "Single id "VIP""**
This also I able to convert into json object by decoding all special characters but in that case I am getting a array of strings not array of Objects of details.

```
Class details
{
    Public string IdKey;
    Public string IdNumber;
    Public string IdType;
    Public string IdTitle;
    Public string Name;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is javascript?

Comment: FWIW, there is no such 'JSON Object'. You are trying to convert a JSON string to an JS Object Literal.

Comment: It's look like [tag:c#]

Comment: I think maybe you should rewrite your question somewhat, what is it you are trying to achieve, getting some data converting it JS and manipulating, then transforming back into JSON to be sent back to the server? Also as a side note, you don't need jQuery, like at all when working with JS and JSON

Comment: @Leonel not to me it doesn't.. there are not auto properties, the casing is all wrong

Comment: The class I have just added to show what kind of object I am getting.
I am able to convet first string into JSON but when it has some special characters like " or ' then I am not able to convert it into JSON. And I am doing all this in JQuery only.

Comment: escape all your strings

Comment: @CerlinBoss I have tried with escape also.
But for second string that I have added, Its not working with that too. :(

Comment: have you tried using something like [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: I don't have any idea of gson.

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert this

```
var JsonString = "{"IdKey":"100008000","IdNumber":"50111112","IdType":"Single","IdTitle":"Singel Id","Name":"Nick"}";
```

with double quotes
into
single quotes

```
var JsonString = '{"IdKey":"100008000","IdNumber":"50111112","IdType":"Single","IdTitle":"Singel Id","Name":"Nick"}';
```

Then JSON parse will work correctly without any parsing error.
var **JsonObject** = JSON.parse(JsonString);

Comment: Here "IdTitle":"Singel Id "VIP"" instead of "IdTitle":"Singel Id"

That's why I am not able to convert it.

Comment: @RahulKhandelwal Then you should create your own custom function that can handle this type of incorrect JSON and can convert it into a valid/correct JSON object.

Answer (score -1):

**Here is the custom function that can handle incorrect JSON and can convert it into a valid/correct JSON object and also you can update this to handle any type of incorrect JSON.**

```
var JsonString = '{"IdKey":"100008000","IdNumber":"50111112","IdType":"Single","IdTitle":"Singel Id "VIP"","Name":"Nick"}'; // Incorrect JSON Object

function convertToJSON() {
    var newJsonStringObj = {};
    JsonString = JsonString.replace(/["{}]/g, '');
    var JsonStringArray = JsonString.split(",");
    var arrKey = '';
    var arrVal = '';
    var JsonStringArrayKeyValue = '';
    for(var i=0; i<JsonStringArray.length; i++) {
        arrKey = '';
        arrVal = '';
        JsonStringArrayKeyValue = '';
        JsonStringArrayKeyValue = JsonStringArray[i].split(":");
        arrKey = JsonStringArrayKeyValue[0];
        arrVal = JsonStringArrayKeyValue[1];
        newJsonStringObj[arrKey] = arrVal;
    }
    console.log(newJsonStringObj); // Correct JSON Object
}
convertToJSON();
```

Comment: Appreciated your help Varun.
But this is also not a permanent solution. It will break if JsonString contains colon or comma.
I was looking for a permanent solution that it will not break with any special character.

Comment: @RahulKhandelwal That is what I am saying you can update this to handle all types of incorrect JSON.
Changes to be made in this part.
**JsonString = JsonString.replace(/["{}]/g, '');**